# Microsoft CRM 2015 option sets

Tags: dynamics-crm, html-select

I want to add an option set to a table (CRM entitity). For example in Account, I want to add option set called "Terms Code".  My possible options may be A,B,C,D or E. CRM gives me an underlying numeric value for each option.  Typically these are like 100,000,002 and 100,000,003.

Question: Why such big numbers? Would I be mistaken to change these to 1,2,3.  Also why when I create a Global Option set do I not get these big numbers.

Why I am uncomfortable with this, is because we want to write interfaces to pump data into CRM Account table, and we don't want to have to deal with different numeric values for same option on each organization's server.

Example:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft introduced these big numbers in order to 'namespace' them. The idea is that option sets can be shared by multiple add-ons for CRM, each of them potentially adding their options to them.

In order to avoid collisions of option numbers created by multiple add-ons, the numbering of option sets is defaulted to a high number that is calculated using the solution publisher's prefix.

Of course, when you are in control of the option sets that uniquely belong to the customizations of your company, there is no reason why you should take numbering collisions into account. In these scenarios you can safely choose the values you need. The page will show a warning every time, but you are safe to ignore that.